# why view in drawerlayout is force scale to fill screen

Tags: android, user-interface

here is my test code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="ro.rotry.NdInnerViewAutoFillScreen">
    <TextView android:text="in drawerlayout" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:background="@android:color/black" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I get following result:

[image]

how to make TextView show 100dp size

**update**

i can fix it with following code:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                     android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView android:text="in coordinator" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:background="@android:color/black" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

but i hope a way without CoordinatorLayout, it's too trouble

Comment: Do you actually need the `DrawerLayout`? You don't have a drawer in that layout.

Comment: @MikeM. it just simple sample to reproduce my question, I need DrawerLayout in real code

Answer (score 2):

The first child `View` of a `DrawerLayout` is the main content `View`, and it will be laid out to fill the `DrawerLayout` regardless of the layout attributes you set on it.

If you want your `TextView` to be the size you set, you need to wrap it in another `ViewGroup` that acts as the main content `View`. For example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ro.rotry.NdInnerViewAutoFillScreen">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView android:text="in drawerlayout"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View android:id="@+id/drawer"
        ... />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```